# BufferedReader readLine remains blocked when using C client and Java server

Tags: java, c, sockets

I am currently working on a C client(A) which will communicate with a Java server(B), who is a client for a RMI server(C). A has to send its arguments to B which will send them to C, C will process them, resend them back to B and B will return them to A. So clearly A has to write to the socket and then remain blocked until B sends something back. The problem I am facing is that after A writes to the socket and remains blocked by select(), B is not unblocked from its own readLine.

If I remove the select() and read() from A, everything will work perfectly. Here's the code

A-client.c

```
    int err;
    err = send(sockfd,(const char*)toSend,size,0);//send counter
    if (err < 0){
        perror("Problem encountered while sending");
        exit(3);
    }
    //it always gets past this line
    fd_set read_set;
    int nb;
    FD_ZERO(&read_set); //initialize variables for select
    FD_SET(sockfd, &read_set); 
    nb = select(sockfd+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (nb!=0){
        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &read_set)) {//if data is incoming from*/

            char word[4096]="";
            if (read(sockfd, word, 4096) == 0){
                perror("The server terminated prematurely");
                exit(4);
            }   
            for (i=0;i<4096;i++){
                printf("%c",word[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

B-server.Java

```
connection = socket1.accept();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
//it always passes this line
String str = br.readLine();
//it passes this line only if i kill the C client or remove the read and select from the client
String[] splitStr = str.split("\\s+");
int argsLen = splitStr.length;
```

Comment: Just a thought, try `recv()` instead of `read`. and pay close attention to the return value, as it is the number of bytes read, or negative on error. In other words, it will *not* return the single value you're testing against. Note: some assembly required. (as in, you will likely get your data in chunks).

Comment: @WhozCraig read() and recv() are identical except on Windows.

Comment: @EJP on the nixes they *both* turn out a 0 on close-connection ? Interesting. thanks for the tip. (and yeah, its Windows where I normally use them, trivial stuff on Linux).

Comment: They behave identically in all respects except for certain flags such as MSG_PEEK. See the *man* pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are reading a line, but are you writing a line? With a line terminator? Clearly not.
2. You are ignoring  the count returned by read() in the server. You can't assume that read() filled the buffer.

Comment: you are spot on! I was ending the line with \0, but with \n it works. Thanks a lot mate!